# Bijection between Q x Q and natural numbers

Tags: analysis

How can I show there's exist Bijection between Q x Q and natural numbers (Q × Q ~ N)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could do this in two steps.

1) There is a bijection between $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb N$ by using the Cantor's first diagonal argument.

2) There is a bijection between $A$ and $A\times A$, where $A$ is a denumerable (i.e., countably infinite) set. Here you can use Cantor's first diagonal argument as well.

The composition of bijective mappings is a bijection. Done.